# Stripe landing page setting not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I'm currently taking an online course to make an airbnb like web application with ruby on rails. It utilizes Stripe for the payment and I want to make the landing page from my app to the Stripe a register page instead of a login page.

I'm completely following the tutorial that successfully makes the register page as the landing page with the below code.

stripe_landing: 'register'

But my landing page is still the login page. I googled the above code but all I could find was pages from 2-4 years ago. I wonder if Stripe changed it recently. (but hpar replied saying nothing has changed)

I put the whole code here... When I click the link to Stripe, it goes to stripe#oauth.

```
    class StripeController < ApplicationController
      # Connect yourself to a Stripe account.
      # Only works on the currently logged in user.
      # See app/services/stripe_oauth.rb for #oauth_url details.

      def oauth
        connector = StripeOauth.new( current_user )
        url, error = connector.oauth_url( redirect_uri: stripe_confirm_url )

        if url.nil?
          flash[:error] = error
          redirect_to manage_listing_payment_path( session[:listing_id] )
        else
          redirect_to url
        end
      end

    end
```

then,

```
    class StripeOauth < Struct.new( :user )

      def oauth_url( params )
        url = client.authorize_url( {
          scope: 'read_write',
          stripe_landing: 'register',
          stripe_user: {
            email: user.email
          }
        }.merge( params ) )

        [ url, nil ]
      end

      # A simple OAuth2 client we can use to generate a URL
      # to redirect the user to as well as get an access token.
      # Used in #oauth_url and #verify!
      # see this docs https://github.com/intridea/oauth2
      def client
        @client ||= OAuth2::Client.new(
          ENV['STRIPE_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID'],
          Stripe.api_key,
          {
            site: 'https://connect.stripe.com',
            authorize_url: '/oauth/authorize',
            token_url: '/oauth/token'
          }
        ).auth_code
      end

    end
```

The terminal says;

Started GET "/connect/oauth" for ::1 at 2017-07-09 00:37:55 +0800
Processing by StripeController#oauth as HTML
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Redirected to https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=ca_AuidWGx68TXWlWO3d3UbWcRcuPqfSeNH&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fconnect%2Fconfirm&response_type=code&scope=read_write&stripe_landing=register&stripe_user%5Bemail%5D=aaa%40gmail.com

so I think I get the right url here (same as the tutorial video gets). However, in Chrome, it actually goes to;

https://connect.stripe.com/login?redirect=%2Foauth%2Fauthorize%3Fclient_id%3Dca_AuidWGx68TXWlWO3d3UbWcRcuPqfSeNH%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fconnect%252Fconfirm%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dread_write%26stripe_landing%3Dregister%26stripe_user%255Bemail%255D%3Daaa%2540gmail.com&force_login=true

Sorry for the poor explanation but it would be great if anyone can solve this mystery. Thanks a lot!

Comment: We love to see some codes or images in other to help with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried on safari and it worked properly so I deleted related cookies on chrome and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has changed about this recently according to Stripe's docs:

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference#get-authorize-request

You can test this by opening this example link:

https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ca_32D88BD1qLklliziD7gYQvctJIhWBSQ7&scope=read_write&stripe_landing=register

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried the example link and got this. It's still the login page and I wonder if I set up anything wrong because there is "force_login=true" at the end of the url. If you have any idea...

https://connect.stripe.com/login?redirect=%2Foauth%2Fauthorize%3Fresponse_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3Dca_32D88BD1qLklliziD7gYQvctJIhWBSQ7%26scope%3Dread_write%26stripe_landing%3Dregister&force_login=true